# Convert html into an equivalent one line file with extra spaces removed?

Tags: javascript, html, xquery

I want to convert an HTML file to an equivalent one line HTML file with extra spaces removed. The following command can concatenate all lines into one line. But I am not sure if the resulted file is always equivalent to the original (for example there might be embedded javascript code or css code and comments that makes the problem complicated.). It also does not remove extra spaces. Here, "equivalent" means that a browser would treat the converted HTML file and the original HTML file the same.

```
gawk -v ORS= 1 < x.html
```

Could anybody show me the command to achieve the goal? Any solution is welcome (may or may not in awk)?

Comment: A small example of the data you're working with and an example of how you want it to
look after processing will help people answer the question for you. Since then
1) there is no ambiguity and 2) people can copy the examples and experiment
with it to build a good answer. Cheers!

Comment: Use a program like https://github.com/wilsonzlin/minify-html

Comment: You **cannot** do this with awk (or sed) so I'm removing those tags. I don't think you can do it with the usual XML aware tools either since they typically ignore comments.

Comment: @mattb No. An example is not helpful, as I am asking for an arbitrary HTML input.